# First In First Out (or similar) with OutputStream

Tags: java, android, stream, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I am getting data bytes (stream) from the Android Camera and then I append them (using OutputStream) to a file (text.data) which I am thereafter is planning to read with ffmpeg. However, this file will surely grow and I need a way that after a certain amount of time, let's say 30 seconds, of writing, I need to delete the initial part of the file (which perhaps corresponds to 10 seconds). This is what I mean with First In First Out. In this moment I don't know how big the file will be with 30 seconds but I guess that is something I can figure out with trial.

Is this even possible? If yes, can someone help out?

Edit: on 2nd thoughts, I guess I would need to use a buffer and when it is full, I write the file or something similar...

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
Camera.PreviewCallback callback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //Do your processing here... Use the byte[] called "data"
            Log.d("Cam ","Cam preview callback");
        try {
            File f=new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.data");
            if(!f.exists()){
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f,true);

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            int imageFormat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
            if (imageFormat == ImageFormat.NV21) {
                Camera.Size previewSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
                int frameWidth = previewSize.width;
                int frameHeight = previewSize.height;
                Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
                YuvImage img = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, frameWidth, frameHeight, null);
                outStream.write(data);                   
                outStream.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException iex){
            Log.d("File :-",iex.getMessage());

        }
        catch (IOException iexp){
            Log.d("File :-","IOExcp"+iexp.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Consider writing to a set of files with a size of your choice.  Then simply delete      the first.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer: that's a nice idea.